# Using map to generate a sequence of SwiftChart objects from coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, swiftcharts

I am trying to iterate over an Array of coordinates to create an object from each coordinate. The coordinates are stored as tuples `(x,y,z,label)`.

```
private enum University 
{
     case Uni0,Uni1,Uni2, Uni3
}

let models: [(x: CGFloat, y:CGFloat, r:CGFloat, type: University)] = [
        (246.56, 138.98, 1,.Uni0), (218.33, 132.71, 1,.Uni0), (187.79, 127.48, 1, .Uni0), (150.63, 135.5, 1, .Uni0), (185.05, 152.57, 1, .Uni3), (213.15, 155.71, 1, .Uni1), (252.79, 158.85, 1, .Uni2), (315.77, 150.62, 1, .Uni0), (220.55, 149.57, 1, .Uni3)
```

**Line that generates the error**

```
let xValues = models{$0.x}.map{ChartAxisValueInt($0.x,labelSettings: labelSettings)}
```

`ChartAxisValueInt` is a class from SwiftCharts. The constructor takes an `Int` and an instance of `ChartLabelSettings`.

The error message says that *map cannot be invoked with an argument list of type ((_) -> _ ).

I believe `map` is appropriate because I want to generate one sequence by appyling a function to each member of another series.

More confusingly, the below example code from SwiftCharts does not generate that error:

```
let xValues = Array(stride(from: 0, through: 450, by: 50)).map {ChartAxisValueInt($0, labelSettings: labelSettings)}
```

Comment: You need to call map only once: `let xValues = models.map{ChartAxisValueFloat($0.x, labelSettings: labelSettings)}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there is simply a `map()` call missing,

```
let xValues = models{ $0.x }.map{ ... }
```

should be

```
let xValues = models.map{ $0.x }.map{ ... }
```

In addition, `ChartAxisValueInt()` takes an `Int` as first argument,
but your x-coordinates are `CGFloat`s. So this would work:

```
let xValues = models
    .map { $0.x }
    .map { ChartAxisValueFloat($0, labelSettings: labelSettings) }
```

However, as @Ixx correctly noticed, the same can be done more
effectively in a single mapping:

```
let xValues = models
    .map { ChartAxisValueFloat($0.x, labelSettings: labelSettings) }
```

Comment: I rather would say `models.map{...}`, otherwise you iterate through all the values 2x and this is not necessary in this case.